# SceneKit Model Wooden Material looks like Bronze in App

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit

Having problem with SceneKit object. Trying to get it to look like the first image below, but in the application it looks like plastic bronze.

**Object in Xcode / SceneKit**
[image: SceneKit Preview]

**Object in AR app**
[image: SceneKit result in ARKit]

Can't really figure out what am doing wrong but have narrow it down to my material settings. Current settings:

**Materials** settings in Xcode
[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning specular map for diffuse, specular and metalness which is wrong.

PBR lights have four important components which are

> Diffuse, Roughness, Metal and Normal

Assign these properties with the right map and you will have the expected result.

[image]
For More details on PBR check [this link](https://medium.com/@avihay/amazing-physically-based-rendering-using-the-new-ios-10-scenekit-2489e43f7021)